# ng is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-7, angular, angular-cli

Running windows 7 Professional 32bit.

I tried running `npm install -g angular-cli` both under normal or admin.
[image: 2016-06-23_14h46_40]

I also tried adding it to the Enviorment Variables under PATH: `(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng)` , with no success also.
[image: 2016-06-23_14h56_48]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you want the *directory* (`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin`) in `%PATH%`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried it just to see if 'ng' works, but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you open a new command prompt? Environment variables won't be propagated to running ones. Try `echo %PATH%` to see that it's correct.

Comment: Well, check that `%PATH%` contains (it's a semicolon-separated list) the directory that contains `ng.exe`.

Comment: the path is in there, check it out:  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-m3lh5ob7YQY/V2vbE82_KAI/AAAAAAAATsI/KtFemTgen-YXJoGgL4AoA_zZCaprCQf8gCCo/s677/2016-06-23_15h48_52.jpg

Comment: That doesn't look like a path to a *directory*. Isn't the directory called `bin`, and the *file in the directory* called `ng.exe`?

Comment: I think i know what u mean. U say it should stop at \bin, and not at \bin\ng, and you are right! But do you know how can i edit that path? I just did `npm install -g angular-cli` and it must have set the wrong path.

Comment: You said you added it in *System Properties* > *Environment Variables*. Just edit it there.

Comment: Could you post the output of `dir C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin` (better copy the path from `%PATH%`)?

Comment: In that folder it's a `ng` file with no extension that has javascript code. It's not an exe. Here is a pic with the output: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fZYHp-H2nQ8/V2v2qUlEFHI/AAAAAAAATsY/X3IneR3FIlknjr9y7m7yYa_WkZ-KNxUdwCCo/s677/2016-06-23_17h46_50.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for 'sort' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-sort-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comma)

Comment: First I updated 'node' then run '@angular/cli' command in administrator mode, It's fixed my issue.

Comment: i found the solution for that problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874999/7968316

Comment: @Cristian Muscalu Or you can simply **run `cmd` as admin** (if you can) and install angular-cli from there. so environment variables would be automatically fixed for you.

Comment: Here's an in depth article that halped me, [how to fix ng is not recognized as internal or external command](https://semicolon.dev/angular/how-to-fix-ng-is-not-recognized-as-internal-command-error)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved it few days ago, after having the same problem with other global modules, by adding to:

**Environment Tables -> System variables -> Path:**

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

> **Note that it must not have any spaces after ;**

That turned out to be my problem.

Comment: Look up the path for file ng.cmd. Update the environment variable PATH value with the same path path. Restart the command line console and you are done.

Comment: The answer below "npm config get prefix" is the correct approach

Comment: unless you see the `ng` in the folder is `ng.cmd` or `Windows Command Script` under Type column, else this **ng** in this `angular-cli\bin` does not work.

Comment: this answer needs updating, as now the path in CLI v7.0+ is C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 513):

I solved this problem in accordance with the figure:

**run in cmd**

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**and then**

( open in Windows 10) Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
or accordance with the figure

**step 1:**

[image]

**step 2 :**

[image]

**step3:**

[image]

**step4:**

[image]

**step5: add missing ng path**

```
C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\{yourusername}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

[image]

Here is new environment variable that you need add: `C:\Users\PK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`

Finally, **restart all opened command prompts** and try again.

Comment: you got the Angular and NG comments (in res) the wrong way round ;)

Comment: in my case i only needed to add the path to npm.

Comment: You don't have to restart the computer at the end, u just have to restart the command prompt.

Comment: Or you can log off ("sign out" in win 10 language), and then log back on.  That will "reset" all your environment variables.  But that is small potatoes....next to the this actual-answer.  Upvote.  Thanks.

Comment: `C:\Users\<YOURUSER>\AppData\Roaming\npm` is not Angular path but npm path, so if you add this path to your environmental variables, then all the npm packages you install with -g flag will be available on your command line (not only ng).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing explanation and details.
Worked like a charm.
Running on Windows 10 and I didn't needed to reboot.

Comment: Perfect, after pulling my hairs for 5 hours I got this correct solution. Thank you very much @BehrouzMoslem.
My errors are gone and now I run angularCli commands

Comment: Rather than `C:\Users\<YOURUSER>\AppData\Roaming\npm`, you can use `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` without having to type in your username.

Comment: In my situation, order lines has been effected to work. When I firstly enter @angular line, and after npm line is not worked ( In Visual Studio Code ). Thanks.

Comment: %appdata%\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin is enough. No need for absolute path.

Comment: This instructions are overcomplicated, just hit the WINDOWS key and type "Environment" to go to the environment variables

Comment: For Windows and Bash usage, I ended up adding the following to my ~/.bashrc in order to get things working. `PATH=$PATH:~/AppData/Roaming/npm:~/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin`

Comment: no need to restart command lines after put the path

Answer (score 354):

For me it works with:

```
npm run ng <command>
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why it is so and how can we get rid of 'npm run' ?

Comment: but this does omit any additional parameters after ng build

Comment: For direct running through `ng` command you can link your `@angular/cli` with npm using 

`npm link  @angular/cli`

Comment: @PratikGandhi This is because `cmd` can only run commands specified in the environment variables (in this case `npm`). This path is added when you install node in your system globally. 
When you add the complete path `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng` to environment variables and rerun `cmd`, it will accept `ng` as a command.
Alternatively, you can also use Node.js command prompt to run ng commands.

Comment: @hakuna You can pass in additional parameters to the `ng` command via `npm run ng serve -- --port=12345`. Note the two separate sets of dashes.

Comment: This also applies if you setup your Angular project via Visual Studio template.

Comment: `npm`, but also `yarn` or another package manager

Comment: I wanted to run ng serve -o and have the browser open up a tab automatically, so using the example provided by @krillgar, that became `npm run ng serve -- -o`

Comment: @Pratik the reason could be your node version changed!

Answer (score 139):

Adding `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm` to System Variable `Path` worked for me. Please find your appropriate file path to 'npm'

Also, check if you have added your `angular-cli\bin` path to the path variable.

Comment: Also try restarting PC. After that ng command started working.

Comment: Look up the path for file "ng.cmd". update the environment variable PATH with the path.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10, but I added "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm" to cover multiple potential users pulling from their own user profiles.

Comment: `%AppData%\npm` will expand to both @TimMcElwee and @sabari's values, and are user and machine agnostic.

Comment: adding the \npm folder to path variables fixed it for me

Answer (score 98):

I am using WIN 10, just figure it out for this problem.
Type the code below in cmd:

**npm config get prefix**

and **copy&paste** the path that you get it from the top into your computer environment variables-->user variables box --> path --> edit -- **C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_global**, your path may different.

Click Ok and **reopen** your cmd window, type in **ng version**, then it works! Cheers!

Comment: Works like a charm! 
MySQL shell overrode my user path variable.. :(

Comment: Didn't work for me. `npm config get prefix` told me my directory was C:\Users\PhilVanKleur\AppData\Roaming\npm\ . But there's nothing in it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in Win 10 on my Dev box. I have also installed Chocolatey and ran the "refreshenv" command after adding the folder which was yielded into the user environment PATH variable and avoided to have to refresh my terminal window.

Answer (score 54):

Just open your command prompt (run as administrator). Ensure `node --v` is 6.9.0 or higher and `npm --v` is 3.0.0 r higher.

After that run the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Once angular is installed. you can see an entry of angular cli in the path

```
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

Then try ng help. It will work.

Comment: running as administrator seems to be the key bit

Answer (score 50):

1) Enter below command on command prompt

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

2) Make sure that **C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm** this path is **not hidden**.

3) Add **C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm** and

**C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm \node_modules@angular\cli\bin** to both enviroment variable **path**.

4) Open new command prompt and type **ng help**. It will work.

Comment: I could not see the AppData directory until I got admin permission for my Windows 10 machine and then opened up a command window by clicking Run as Administrator.

Comment: I had that folder hidden but it still worked. This is the best solution. As an FYI if needed: you separate the paths with a semi-colon so it becomes:

```<what's already there>;C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm \node_modules@angular\cli\bin```

Answer (score 23):

With a command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It works fine, I am able to run ng command now.

Comment: I ran npm install -g @angular/cli@latest from folder c:\Temp.  It did not install to C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\npm \node_modules@angular\cli\bin. It created C:\Temp\node_modules instead. I'm very new to this but I thought -g (global) would put it in ..Appdata\Roaming\npm..

Answer (score 22):

I followed below steps for resolution for this issue in **Windows 10**:

1. First make sure you have installed Angular CLI . You can use below
   to install same.

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

2. Make sure that AppData is visible and navigate to path below.

> C:\Users\rkota\AppData\Roaming\npm

Same path can be found by running below too:

> npm config get prefix

3. Add the above path i.e. " C:\Users\rkota\AppData\Roaming\npm" in Environment variable PATH and make sure it got added by running path in command prompt.
4. Close command prompt and now try to run below:

> ng --version

you will be able to see CLI version.

Answer (score 19):

General problem is that OS tries to find the PATH variable with `ng` keyword and cannot find it.
For me, even after the steps [@behrouzmoslem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4746570/behrouzmoslem) suggested in the top answers to this post I didn't manage to get it work, because after the launch of ng command OS started to respond, but opens up editor file by the path `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng` which is actually funny. So, solution is:

Just use `npx` before any angular executables.

Eg : `npx ng serve` for serving the angular app or `npx ng build --watch` to build with watcher.

Comment: Finally! Something that works. I have to run everything from a separate admin account on my machine due to my organisation's security policies. This is the first solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

execute following lines in order to solve the issue for both not found and undefined version of ng

npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using the in-built command prompt better start using the NodeJS installed version of command prompt. Then it is going to work perfectly without any issues.[image]

Comment: Running `where ng` within that console might help to find out what is wrong with the path. That did it for me, ng was resolved in the wrong user AppData, hence executing a bad version of the cli.

Answer (score 12):

If you get the error even after following the above step. then try below.

Since it is a node script. I am using the below option to create as of now.

node C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng version

May be symbolic links are required. Not researched further.

On Further Research:
Set Path as : %PATH%;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;

In Windows, npm.cmd file is in the above path. If the above Environment variable is set, you can execute as 
ng version
ng init

Answer (score 9):

for me it works only with the flag **--force**:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --force
```

If everything is fine then you shoud see the folder **node_modules** in this path:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Comment: It's working. thanks. Most of office system is shared workspace like citrix. so, we can't find C drive. But this command will helps to do ng version avail globally. thanks

Answer (score 8):

1. Open cmd and type `npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. In environment variables, add either in the user variable or System variable "Path"  value=`C:\Users\your-user\.npm-packages\node_modules\.bin`
3. In cmd: `c:\>cd your-new-project-path`
4. `...\project-path\> ng new my-app`

   or **`ng all-ng-commands`**

Answer (score 8):

I resolved by adding - %AppData%\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ path to my environment variables path

Answer (score 7):

close cmd and open it again with admin right or reboot ur system.

Answer (score 6):

I faced same issue when i tried to install angular cli locally with command

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

After that i got same issue
C:\Users\vi1kumar\Desktop\tus\ANGULAR\AngularForms>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Than i tried to install it globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

In this case it worked I was wondering that is it not possible to install cli globally ?

After doing some research I found this article very helpful hope it will help someone facing similar issue

[Working with multiple versions of Angular CLI](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-5-or-angular-6-yes-please-d71b08b5e59b)

Answer (score 5):

This one almost worked for me, but I had to use: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
. In Environment Variables.../System variables/Path

Then when I did CMD: "ng -v" I got the correct response for angular cli.

Answer (score 5):

`npm install -g @angular/cli` helped for me instead of `npm install @angular/cli`

Answer (score 5):

#### 1- Install

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

#### 2- Make sure where your `ng.cmd` is present.

[image]

#### 3- Then add this path into variables.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Windows 7, 64 bits running with npm  v3.10.8.

1. I added the path as it was suggested: ( C:\Users.....(your user name)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng) and uninstalled angular-cli.
2. After this, I cleared the npm cache by `npm cache clean` as prompted here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems/. This guarantees there are no leftovers.
3. Reinstalled angular-cli with `npm install -g angular-cli`and voila.
   Hope that may be useful!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I did below steps.

All Programs -> Node JS-> Right click on Node.js Command Prompt and select properties and from Target string at end copy below

```
/k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"
```

I launched Visual Studio Code and opened below file

`C:\Users\gochinta\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` and gave below

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": 
  ["/k", "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nodevars.bat"]

}
```

Now I typed `ng -v` in my Visual Studio Code Terminal window and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when tried with the syntax "ng new " and solved that simply by updating the existing node version from 5.x.x to 8.x.x. After successful updation of node, the syntax worked perfectly for me. Please update the existing version of node. As it is clearly mentioned in angular documentation that these commands require the node version >= 6.9.x. For reference please check https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. It clearly states "Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine".

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue on x86, windows 7;

- uninstalled @angular/cli
- re-installed @angular/cli
- checked & verified environmental variables (no problems there)...
- Still same issue:

**Solution** was the .npmrc file at C:\Users{USERNAME}... change the prefix so that it reads "prefix=${APPDATA}\npm"... Thanks to [this](http://itechiesol.blogspot.com/2017/07/angular-cli-ng-command-is-not-working.html) website for help in resolving it

Answer (score 3):

For me something was wrong in the PATH enviroment variable. I removed all path related to npm and added at the **start** of PATH this folder:

```
c:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Make sure you have `;` between paths.

Comment: this is the right one, because both Win7 & 10 have ng. **cmd** file here.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is still asked over and over again one year later I will post my answer here as well.

**The clue (on Windows only) is to arrange the entries in the path variable right.**

As the [NPM wiki tells us](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows):

> Because the installer puts C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs before C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm on your PATH, it will always use version of npm installed with node instead of the version of npm you installed using `npm -g install npm@<version>`.

So your path variable will look something like:

`…;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;…`

Now you have two possibilities:

1. Swap the two entries so it will look like

```
…;%appdata%\npm;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;…
```

This will load the npm version installed with npm (and not with node) and with the installed Angular CLI version.

2. If you (for whatever reason) like to use the npm version bundled with node, add the direct path to your global Angualr CLI version. After this your path variable should look like this: `…;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;…` 
   or `…;%appdata%\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;…`
   for the short form.

This worked for me since a while now.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same issue and it's get resolved. At my end reason is i install node and **CLI** using other user profile and now i am running ng command from other user login. Since node and cli installed using other user login node is not finding anything on `C:\Users\&lt;user name&gt;\AppData\Roaming` this path and that's why i am getting this error.

I run `npm install -g @angular/cli` command and restart my machine. Every thing is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime in the future. Applicable to Windows 8.1 machine.
Run the following commands

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Log out or restart your machine.

This should add the required env path, rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to play with cmd by setting environment variable path & etc, but simple answer is use nodejs command prompt.

So you no need to set environment variable path or anything. When you insalled nodejs it will give it's command prompt, by using that you us "ng" command, without any settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of Visual Studio Code not being able to run any ng commands in it's built in terminal.

I added %AppData%\npm to the path in Windows 10, and did not have to reboot, just closed and reopened VS Code and not it sees it.

Comment: same issue  i set new path to `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng` and it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Install **x32 version nodejs** instead of **x64 version** (even on 64-bit windows machine).

Comment: Run `npm run ng serve` for a dev server. Navigate to `http://localhost:PORT YOU DEFINE IN APPSETTINGS/`. The app will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.

Comment: @NitishKumar , Why a x32 version instead of x64 on a 64-bit windows?

Answer (score 1):

I was also following this problem so I tried this command and it worked perfectly.
Use this command: npm run ng

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and have gone through the following path -
 (***%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm***) and came to know that there is some junk data and when I cleared everything under npm directory. Now when I ran (***npm install*** command again). Now everything works fine.

Comment: This helped for me!

Answer (score 1):

Navigate the directory where you want to create the application and run the command:

**PATH="Path where your node is installed";%PATH%**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it completely by running **VS Code as Administrator**.

I used the above mentioned solutions (npm install -g @angular/cli@latest & npm install @angular/cli in my project), tried ng serve both in cmd and VS Code terminal but didn't work, while npm run ng serve could run in VS Code terminal, but I wasn't satisfied with that. 
After that I set the path in the environment variables exactly like this "C:\Users\TheUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm" and still wasn't able to run ng serve.

Then I ran VS Code as Administrator and it finally worked. It even recognized another command, gulp, which didn't recognize till then, even though I had it also correctly installed. Not sure why it had this behavior and I would like an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

After installation:
Go to start Menu
Type Environment variable
click on "edit the system environment variables", It will open a window
In window, click on "Environment variable" button
Double click on "Path" then click on new and add the below environment variable
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm (or open run window type %AppData% and open npm folder there. Provide this location in environment variable.)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 pro:

1. Install Node and restart the device.
2. Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`.
3. Restart system.

Note: Don't forget `-g` in command.

Answer (score 0):

Set path=%path%;C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PATH environment variable should be updated by adding following path,

```
C:\Users\xyzname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

Because ng file is in bin folder, once this is added for sure ng will be  recognized

Answer (score 0):

try to set system variable path with `%AppData%\npm\`. and make sure visibility of AppData folder. this folder should be visible (not hidden).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the npm path to the user PATH environment variable as well. You can do that by running the following PowerShell script as admin:

```
$path = npm config get prefix    
$userPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")

if (($userPath -split ';') -notcontains $path) 
{
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ('{0};{1}' -f $userPath, $path), "User")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before try to update the PATH varibles on Windows 7 (x64), run CMD console AS ADMINISTRATOR and ng command works for me, this also applied to VISUAL STUDIO CODE Console.

It worked for me on both CMD CONSOLE / VS CODE

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even though `%appdata%\npm` was already in PATH, I had to delete and add it again in the system variable editor. Restarting OS / reinstalling Angular CLI did not help for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Windows 10.
The user's %Path% environment already had the required "C:\Users\ *user* \AppData\Roaming\npm".

path command would not show it, but it did show tons of other paths added earlier by other installations.

Turned out I **needed to delete some of them from the system's PATH environment variable.**

As far as I understand this happens because there's a length limit on these variables: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/limitation-to-the-length-of-the-system-path-variable

Probably happens often on dev machines who install lots of stuff that needs to be in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js command prompt and execute the command

> ng version

It should work.

---

If you're looking to actually find where `ng` is located you can then type `where ng` and it will show you which `ng` is running (eg. `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`). You can then look at your path and see if adding that folder is helpful. The Node.js command prompt adds extra paths that may be missing from your path.

Comment: Ok so this is an interesting answer. I change my user home directory (to remove a space) and then my `ng` was no longer in the path. I've edited the answer to add next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a global Angular install, only project level. One of my projects kept throwing this error while others with same setup worked fine! I just

1. Removed the `node_modules` folder from the project
2. Ran `npm i` in the project

Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Yarn**

After doing a `yarn global add @angular/cli` the `ng` command was not recognized even after cmd window restart.

The solution for me was to add either

- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` to the USER environment variable `PATH`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Yarn\bin` to the SYSTEM environment variable `PATH`.

*Installing **Yarn** with `npm install -g yarn` did not add those paths for me for some reason, idk if it should or shouldn't but I cant remembering needing to do so previously on other machines I have had.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to avoid global installation of angular cli. You can add script command to package.json as below

```
"scripts": {
     ....
    "create":"ng g c components/auth-extensions"
  }
```

and run the command

```
npm run create
```

Once your job is done, you can delete the command from package.json.

This avoids installing global package, environment variable, path etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install angular cli globally and starting from scratch then try following steps

1. go to your workspace (cd ./path_to_your_workspace) .
2. $npm init (This will generate package.json)
3. $npm i @angular/cli
4. update package json script section
5. $npm run ng ... (Add prefix npm run to your angular commands)

   ```js
     "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve",
       "build": "ng build",
       "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
       "test": "ng test",
       "e2e": "ng e2e"   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

npm install -g @angular/cli

install this and set path in environment variable

https://angular.io/cli

Project name
**my-first-project**

ng new my-first-project    // To create Project

cd my-first-project

ng serve

Answer (score -1):

Set the new path to `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng`  It works fine now  for me

Answer (score -1):

Add the **ng** command path from the folder **.bin** under the **node_modules** to PATH variable in the system env settings.

e.g: add `C:\testProject\node_modules\.bin\` to `PATH`

Restart your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

You can check in this way. I had the same problem. First, check your user PATH in the environment variable.That must point to `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\`

Instead of command prompt use the node.js command prompt. Run node.js command prompt from installed program menu. Go to start and search for node.js command prompt. Run it then type `ng -v` hit enter. It will work. Let me know your if it helps or not.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Right on **powershell** and Run **as Administrator**

**Step 2:** Run below command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

**Step 3:** To confirm , **run** below command, it should display version.

```
ng version
```