# Angular 2 RC 6 AoT Compiler not working

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-compiler

I just updated my project to Angular 2 RC 6. I am now trying to use Ahead of Time (AoT) Compilation as mentioned in blog post http://angularjs.blogspot.com/ but no success.

I am not using angular cli as I building project in ASP.Net.

As the blog post suggests, I have installed @angular/compiler-cli

But when I try to run ngc from command prompt it gives error

```
'ngc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


npm run ngc
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ngc"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3

npm ERR! missing script: ngc
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Project\App\npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone please guide how to use AoT compiler with ASP.Net Project. Or when you are not using Angular CLI but building components etc manually.

**Edit**

I now managed to run ngc by first moving to **./node_modules/.bin/** and then running

```
ngc -p D:\Project\App
```

But now the compiler is throwing the below error:

When I try to compile my project with ngc, it throws the below error:

```
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 92:25 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in
```

In my App Module I have the below providers and probably this is causing the project. I am not sure what exactly is wrong with this?

```
providers: [
        GlobalService,
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, globalService: GlobalService) => new HttpLoading(backend, defaultOptions, globalService),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, GlobalService]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: If you look at the answer, it's a windows issue somehow your PATH might have gotten screwed up, or you need to restart, or even open CMD as an Admin. It could be many things unfortunately. Give those a shot!

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply, Can you please have a look at the Edit I made to the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
        GlobalService,
        {
            provider: Http, // <-- I believe you were missing the "r" in provide"r"
        }
```

Take a look at the rc6 breaking changes:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue using

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1"
```

For me deleting /node_modules/@angular folder and running

```
npm install
```

Seemed to resolve my issue.  My copy of the package must have gotten mucked up

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

When running scripts from package.json or "npm scripts", to fix the path issue on Windows 10, you need to wrap the directory_path in double quotes, and escape each double quote with a backslash:

`"compile:aot": \"./node_modules/.bin/ngc\" -p src`

This would execute the `ngc` program located in `./node_modules/.bin` with `-p src` arguments.

Otherwise, you have to `cd ./node_modules/.bin && ngc -p src` as 2 different commands.

**Problem 2**

Currently it seems that AOT compilation for angular 2 has a problem with `require()` statements. So if you want to eliminate the compilation errors, you have to remove all require() statements from your app.

Obviously, this is a bad idea since there is value to require(), especially when working with Webpack or other module bundlers. We have to wait for a solution from the angular2 team.

Comment: Hi @TetraDev, re. problem 2, do you any more source of info for this AOT Vs `require()` problem? I could not find any, but I'm hitting that when I try to require a "global" CSS file and doing AOT build in production. Thanks

Comment: @Superjos Yes, instead of `require('my.css');` just do  `import 'my.css';` and AOT will compile fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forgot about my question. At some point we adopted the same workaround as you. Later, upgrading dependencies to the latest currently available, I found out that `require()` works again. Try with @angular 2.1.0 dependencies, and if not enough also with webpack 2.1.0-beta.25

Comment: FYI there is a PR on the way which accepts require. https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12405

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is that you have function calls in your @NgModule definitions. 
I have to remove some dynamic providers to make it work for me.

Maybe you should try to replace your 'useFactory: (...)=>{...}' or at least test commenting it.

Comment: I guess functions in module definitions are in runtime so AOT will definitely fail.