# Angular-cli failed to install properly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I wonder if you can help me.

I tried to install the angular-cli by the npm command

npm install -g angular-cli, however I got a lot of messages, and 'ng' command does not work.

Some of the errors I got are as following

```
> node-zopfli@1.4.0 install C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli
```

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.5.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v6.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
npm WARN install:node-zopfli@1.4.0 node-zopfli@1.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN install:node-zopfli@1.4.0 Exit status 1

> node-sass@3.10.0 install C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.0/win32-x64-48_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node

> node-sass@3.10.0 postinstall C:\Users\my name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Do I need to install anything other then node.js?

Im quite new to Angular, trying to do some tutorials and experiments

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What is your OS and what is your node and npm version ?

Comment: I've just posted a possible solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642595/6306909

Answer (score 1):

I am not on Windows but what you should consider doing first, run command line with administrative privileges. select the application on secondary menu (right click) select runs as admin.

Before that make sure you have installed the latest version of node.js. and the run the following commands.

`npm uninstall -g angular/cli
 npm cache clean
 npm install -g angular/cli@latest`

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the same errors.  It does install an angular-cli in my Roaming/npm/node_modules but when I try ng --help, its telling me that 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: I was thinking of running Linux on Hyper-V, do you think its worth the hassle?  Would it run smoother maybe?

Comment: installed a VM and angular cli running there now.

Comment: For your first question you can fix it as explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: It would run better but with windows you just need to set up everything right. But if you move to linux the better.

Comment: already tried that, did not work. Installation of cli is not working, not a PATH issue

Comment: i will try again in a couple of days, yes working in windows would be easier and faster

Comment: It is because angular/cli is not installed properly in your machine

Answer (score 1):

set environment variable `PYTHON`, with value of full path where `python.exe` is installed.
If its `C:\Program Files\Python34\` then value will be `C:\Program Files\Python34\python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

An update on this.  I installed the new node.js V6.6.0, uninstalled the Angular-Cli, cleaned cache and re-installed the clie and it seems to have done the trick since I was able to install the Angular-CLI without problems this time, and ng new is working.