# Unable to install angular-cli Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular-cli and am encountering the following error, I am running cmd as admin: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined. I have node version v14.15.0 and npm version 6.14.8 and have uninstalled and deleted node_modules and reinstalled nodejs, not sure if is a versions issue. The log is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose npm-session 1371be47c047d421
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 61ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
10 verbose stack     at regFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js:88:23)
10 verbose stack     at fetchPackument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:42:10)
10 verbose stack     at packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:20:10)
10 verbose stack     at getManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:22:10)
10 verbose stack     at manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:13:10)
10 verbose stack     at Object.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\index.js:17:12)
10 verbose stack     at Object.Fetcher#manifest [as manifest] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\genfun\lib\genfun.js:15:38)
10 verbose stack     at manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetch.js:23:18)
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\manifest.js:24:12
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:29:24
10 verbose stack     at Promise._execute (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:313:9)
10 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:488:18)
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
10 verbose stack     at _inflight (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:28:25)
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:22:14
10 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
11 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
13 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
14 verbose node v14.15.0
15 verbose npm  v6.14.8
16 error Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try cleaning cache [like in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544396/11663995). If that doesn’t help there also might be something going on with npm config. To check that type `npm config ls`.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck clearing the cache, is there anything specific I should look for in the config?

Comment: Any overrides related to running scripts might get in the way: `shell`, `script-shell`, `ignore-scripts`. It probably is something else though.