# ng:command not found in node v6.9.1

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to execute an ng command in angular-cli project in my windows 10 PC. node v6.9.1

- Globally installed the angular-cli.
- Tried a fresh npm install.
- Tried adding the path
  ***C:\Users\MohamadS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin***
  in uservariables in the path variable.

Still it says as in the picture.

### [image]

Need help with the issue.

PS- can't use any of the ng commands.( ng g c /componentName/, ng build)

**Edited -**

- Tried the same angular-cli version in the project folder for the global installation as well.

Comment: Are you using cygwin? Maybe just using cmd prompt might make it work.

Comment: @chackerian Thanks for the reply. Tried with command prompt too. it says **'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
But, I do use conemu.

Comment: Check out this: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @AvneshShakya Thanks for the source. Seems it doesn't work and FYI - I've got Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked whether npm path is added to system variable path,
I had the npm v4.0.2 and I simply did an **npm install npm@latest -g**
And once again installed angular-cli -g and now it's working.