# Angular CLI is not installed in windows

Tags: angular

I have the following error When I installed Angular CLI using "npm install -q @angular/cli", I have attached the Screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: that's just a warning for `fsevents is not supported on windows`, just ignore it.

Comment: but he is not able to run ng command also..can you share the screenshot of your global node_modules dir

Comment: Try to run the cmd as administrator and try to install it again

Comment: I guess just uninstall this cli module once "npm uninstall -g @angular/cli". Then run npm cache clean and install again.

Comment: Like brijmcq said, ensure you have privileges to access folders where you are performing installation. Also ensure your global npm folder is in your PATH.

Comment: Please cut and paste the error message as text. We cannot see the screenshot very well.

Comment: Check your path and make sure it includes the correct path for global npm modules. Are any other globally-installed packages working? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8.

Answer (score 3):

Both, the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.
If this doesn't fix your problem, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38142230/6848923

Comment: How would this explain the system not being able to find `ng` to start with?