# Angular 2 production build command line create issue

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-build

I use CLI to run command `npm build` but it is not working

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: your project is created by angular cli ?

Comment: use **ng build** instead of npm build

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng build --prod** instead of npm build

Comment: error:- 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Either you haven't installed the CLI globally or you haven't added your NPM home dir to your PATH?