# After installing Angular in windows - ng is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I tried to install Angular but after installing I got this error

> ng is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable file or batch file

I installed node, npm and git
I then received the below comment for installing Angular. I installed after installing I give ng-v comment I found this error.

> npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Try closing and reopenig the command prompt.

Comment: I tried that but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your node js path ex: " C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm" to System Variable
source :[follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: It worked i simply changed to C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm removing angular-cli in the path

Answer (score 4):

Execute below command:-

npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Try out it for me it worked

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal and try again. Sometimes after installing the package, this error message appears if you use the same window.

If not add it to environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I personally never install angular-cli globally. What I do is -

1. Create a .bin folder some where in your workspace
2. Use npm `npm install  @angular/cli`
3. Come back to your root of workspace
4. Create an angular app using - `.\path to .bin\node_modules\.bin\ng new new-app`

And you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Spent days on this. Had 2 different machines and one worked like a charm the other I ended up uninstalling VS2017, NodeJs to start clean. I would install Nodejs without VS installed. Reinstall NodeJS then angular/cli and no NG recognized using NodeJS command prompt or any other command prompt. On NPM get it said it was installed in path "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA..taco-toolset.." which made no sense since VS was completely gone.
The solution:
In c:\Users\YouUserName.nmprc file persisted after uninstalling Nodejs. Delete this file and reinstalled NodeJS then Angular/cli and all was good.

I think this maybe a result of installing VS2017 with node project types. Not sure but it was one big mess which google lead to no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Add Following path]

Just add path to global npm location:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

The above directory contains "ng" command
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with sudo.
install your node and npm globally

Comment: I installed only globally.And i'm using windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using **VSCode** and **WSL**.

I was trying to generate a service from VSCode's Angular Schematics and got the same issue.

Meanwhile, the path "./node_modules/.bin/ng" was actually there since the beginning while generating the project from angular cli. It's also included on the `devDependencies` section in **package.json** after generating an angular project.

However, it seems that it needs sudo or special permission to invoke the `ng` command from that particular directory. While, there's no way we can override the command from VSCode.

On the other hand, I also had `@angular/cli` installed globally.

Uninstalling the project's (local) @angular/cli should do the trick, by using this command:

`npm uninstall -D @angular/cli`

Therefore, VSCode's angular schematics (or any command that needs it) will try to use the global `@angular/cli` that you've installed beforehand.

In case you haven't install it, then install it using:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`.

That should do the trick.