# Regarding installation of angular cli?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, failed-installation

So, I was trying to install angular cli. Everything seemed fine till completion of process. But, atlast the command of ng -v is showing the command is not recognized.I want to install cli ASAP.Please clarify this anyone?? [image]

Comment: did you forget the `-g` tag when installing? `npm install @angular/cli -g`, may need sudo/admin

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:-

```
1) Install node.js and check and node -v in command prompt. (Node.js 
   through website).
2) npm install -g @angular/cli@latest (run in command prompt).
```

Refer this link for further help  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

```
3) Check node -version
4) Check npm -version
5) check ng -version

If already installed, then uninstall it and install again,
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```