# npm install -g @angular/cli command does not install angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am creating a sample angular2 web app. For that i have installed node.js (v 7.1.0)and NPM (v 3.10.9).
and now after opening system command prompt when I execute the command :
NPM install -g @angular/cli
to install angular cli I am getting the following shown results.
After doing ng -v to check the version of cli installed I am not getting the version number.

Is the cli not installed correctly?
or do I need to set any path variable in environment var?
What has to be done here? Please advise.

```
C:\Users\27727>d:

D:\>cd learn-angular

D:\learn-angular>npm i -g @angular/cli
npm WARN gentlyRm not removing C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd as it w
asn't installed by C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm WARN gentlyRm not removing C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng as it wasn'
t installed by C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
C:\Users\27727\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- @angular/cli@1.7.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@a
ngular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@a
ngular\cli\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fs
events):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed
.

D:\learn-angular>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\learn-angular>
```

Comment: Did you try to reopen your console? Just the first idea that comes in my mind.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: @Kapcash i reopened and tried but the same again...i also tried in Node.js command prompt ...but the ng -v doesnt work. so either the cli is not installed correctly or there some other issue

Comment: @RakeshAR i referred to that post earlier... but the error in my case is different.

Comment: Could you check the module is installed in the global node_module folder? "C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules" :)

Comment: @Kapcash the   \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules has angular-cli and "@angular" folders

Answer (score 0):

In your system please check this path ( `C:\Program Files\nodejs` ) is there in environment  variables.

Comment: I would suggest once remove node JS and install it again

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs is already present in system path shown below :


\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:
\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CA\SC\CAWIN\;C:
\WINDOWS\system32;

Comment: C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm add this path to environment variable