# Angular's - 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angular

C:\Angula2\myapp>ng serve --open
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

and currently i am having node also in my system

C:\Angula2\myapp>node -v
v8.10.0

And How to run Angular4 with out having Admin permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to install `angular-cli` globally to use `ng`

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

to use angular-cli without global installation.

Add `ng serve --open` to the scripts section in your package.json.

```
scripts:{
    "start": ng serve --open
}
```

then run `npm start` in your project directory.

Comment: it isn't mandatory, when you use npm, npm will look for binaries inside `node_modules/bin`, hence npm start will work when angular/cli isn't globally installed. ng will work even in windows when installed globally, as npm creates symlinks for the the npm modules