# Can anyone explain this error when I run "npm run ng new app"?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

So I'm trying to make a new angular app for the first time, and I installed it using `npm i -g @angular/cli`.  When I try to make a new app using `npm run ng new app`, it gives me this error:

> npm ERR! path E:\ddii\package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -4058
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\ddii\package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-10T20_22_50_118Z-debug.log

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the command is ‚ng new <project name>‘ instead of yours. Can you try that?

Comment: @kedenk It said ng not recognized

Comment: Why don't you use "ng new project_name" instead of "npm run ng new app"

Comment: @Raj when I ran ng new project_name it said 'ng is not an internal or external command'

Comment: Please add a screenshot.....and check cmd path where you hit the command...either you don't have angular cli installed or you are in the wrong folder

Comment: @Raj uploaded the error

Comment: What is " ddii " ??? Is this your project name??

Comment: @Raj ddii is the folder i'm trying to do it in.  It gives the exact same errors when I do it without a folder though.

Comment: Please hit the command "ng -v" in cmd prompt in same path ddii and screenshot the result

Comment: @Raj added image

Comment: @Raj any way to explain it?

Comment: Can you please hit the command "ng -v" instead of "npm run ng -v" and share screen shot??

Comment: @Raj if you look at the top of the command prompt in the second screenshot you'll see I already ran the command.

Comment: Please install angular cli by using "npm install -g @angular/cli"

Comment: @Raj did that, and then I got the same error again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you are running the command incorrectly. Remove the `npm run` from the front of your command, and it should work.

When you say `npm run blah`, npm does a lookup in your `package.json` for a script called `blah` or in your case `ng`. So... if you are running `npm run ng new app`, npm wants there to be a `package.json` in your current directory, and in that `package.json`, npm expect a script called `ng`. So if you don't have a `package.json` in your current dir, then you are going to get an error.

Instead, close your terminal, and open a new terminal and run simply `ng new app`.

Comment: I tried that initially and it didn't work, it said `ng is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: On your machine if you type `where ng` does it tell you the location of your global `ng` node module?

Comment: INFO: could not find  files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: This is not always the correct answer, though in most cases it is.  I, for instance, want to rely on the _locally-installed_ `ng`, so i have an `npm-script` for `ng` that invokes `node_modules/.bin/ng`.  I will post an answer that addresses it.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled to find this answer myself, as the other answers on this question do not address the real underlying issue.

All the other answers suggest to install `ng` GLOBALLY using (npm i -g ...), with the side effect that a symlink to `ng` will be on your PATH.

Based on OP's question, I do concede he was most likely attempting to scaffold a new Angular app from the GLOBALLY installed `ng`. So this handles 90% of people's questions, and is all fine and nice.

I, however, want to use the LOCALLY INSTALLED `ng`, which is why I have an `npm-script` in my *package.json* for it:

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
...
    "ng": "ng",
...
}
```

If this describes your use case like it does mine, then read on.

`npm run ng update` succeeds for me, whereas other more complex commands with more arguments—including command-line switches—fail outright (`npm run ng -- update @angular/cli --migrate-only tslint-version-6`).

The answer lies in that you must delimit the start of arguments being passed to `npm run-script` with `--` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/1438576):

```
npm run ng -- update @angular/cli --migrate-only tslint-version-6
```

So in OP's case, assuming he already had a locally-installed copy of `ng` with a package.json (which I admit is doubtful), he could have done:

```
npm run ng -- new app
```

Anyway, hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it without the `npm run ...`, you need to install ng globally, I would do `npm install -g @angular/cli`, however I'm running linux, for windows I've found this thread [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?page=2&tab=active#tab-top)

It should help you install a global version of angular-cli, you'll basically do two things:

1. Install globally angular-cli (if you don't have it).
2. Make sure it's in your environment variable's PATH.

Check the question answers, details are there.

Comment: I did install it globally and it still has the problem.

Comment: @Jodast You have to make sure that your terminal emulator is recognizing `ng`. you have to figure out where global node modules are installed on your machine, and then add that path to the environment variables PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Could help for future references

At least for me this work. 
Sometimes, the reference to the file ng.cmd (in case of Win users) is not well formed and you have to call it and pass the arguments directly

e.g.

< path-where-ng.cmd-file-is-located >\ng.cmd new app

[Running calling ng.cmd file directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Hj8.png)

[It says: ' "ng" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps7bN.png)

And it works even if you do not have admin permissions for any reason