# Problem running ng serve command on Windows 10. This question is different and it is not duplicate

Tags: node.js, angular, installation

I am unable to run ng serve command on Windows 10

I have successfully installed npm and node

I am trying to install angular on Windows 10.

1- My node version is

```
node -v
v10.16.0
```

and npm version is

```
npm -v
6.9.0
```

After running command of angular cli which is

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I am not able to run ng serve command. It show this error

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have looked some online solutions which says to set 'PATH` but my path npm folder is empty

```
C:\Users\shaha\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I have tried many times uninstallation and installation of nodejs but I am unable to run ng serve command. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: did you create a project using `ng new appName`

Comment: please check this url and this may be the possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Yes @DenukaNirmalee but it gives me error ng is not recognized

Comment: @Techiepop I tried that link, but it is not working. C:\Users\shaha\AppData\Roaming\npm in this path npm folder is empty

Comment: @Karan can u check these https://programmingwithmosh.com/angular/common-angular-errors/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Run the following the command to know npm default path
>
> `npm config get prefix`

If the path is different than **AppData/npm** then change it

`npm config set prefix "$APPDATA\npm"`

And again run `npm config get prefix` to get current path then set it to Environment Variables and restart the system

You will need to log out then log back in for the change to your PATH variable to take effect.

Comment: I have npm folder which is empty in this path `C:\Users\shaha\AppData\Roaming\npm` How can I resolve that?

Comment: Npm default path could be changed, Check my updated answer

Comment: Awesome Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Its because of environment path setup

For now you can use `npm run ng serve` command

Answer (score 0):

for run ng serve you can use `npm start`