# how to run ng related commands as its showing error

Tags: angular, angular8

**ng --version**

```
Program 'ng' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation At line:1 char:1
    + ng --version
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~.
    At line:1 char:1
    + ng --version
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I tried to install angular by running `'npm install -g @angular/cli'` command. It installed properly but when I run ng command, it shows the above error.

Comment: Just restart your editor or terminal and try it out. Btw what command did you run?

Comment: If Amit Chigadani's comment doesn't resolve your issue, check [this SO q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) and see if something happened with your PATH env variable

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue and I added the following path to my system variable path :
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm

Then I found ng command is working in my system command prompt but not in Visual Studio Code. Hence I followed the below steps:

- For this click Ctrl+Shift+P and then select "Select Default Shell" option  and choose
  Command prompt.
- Now try running ng command in Visual Code it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install node first - https://nodejs.org/en/
node -v    TO CHECK NODE VERSION

### Uninstall Angular

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

---

ng -v    TO CHECK CLI VERSION

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error comes if you are using **powershell** in VSCode terminal. I just changed it to **cmd promt** and it worked for me.

Comment: yeah right,  i just switched from powershell to comand prompt in vs code and it worked