# issues with installing angular! npm displays 2 warnings while installing

Tags: angular-cli, angular9

command-line text:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>npm install -g @angular/cli

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

@angular/cli@10.1.7 postinstall C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli

node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

@angular/cli@10.1.7
added 276 packages from 206 contributors in 333.421s

C:\Users\User\Desktop>ng new contacts
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Already tried:

1. Added angular to path variables.
2. manually delete npm directory in AppData/Roaming
3. npm clean cache --force

Comment: what version of node.js are you using?

Comment: i am using v12.13.1

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to install latest node packages then you don't need to install angular packages locally

just use npx before ng in every command

```
npx ng new newApp
npx ng serve
npx ng generate component login
npx ng ...
```

this is will work for you.