# Not able to install Angular CLI on machine

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to install Angular CLI using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` but, I am getting the below error when I type `ng` in the command prompt.

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command

command prompt output

```
>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
P:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> P:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@11.0.2 postinstall P:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@11.0.2
updated 1 package in 8.436s
```

Below are the node and npm versions.

```
>node -v
v12.18.2

>npm -v
6.14.5
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: If you are running it into Powershell, then you should try run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`, restart your Powershell, and after, run `ng --version`.

Comment: Were you, previously, able to use other NPM command installed globally ? If not, maybe the global `node_modules` folder is not part of your path.

Answer (score 0):

Install angular forcefully with this:

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli --force
```