# Angular js setup issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

iam rahim here .

> while setuping angularcli i encountred the following issue:
> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ASUS ROG>ng --version

'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> here bellow it show angularcli installed but i failed to found the file in the system:

C:\Users\ASUS ROG>npm list -global

C:\Users\ASUS ROG\AppData\Roaming\npm

+-- @angular/cli@12.1.4

+-- live-server@1.2.1

+-- live@0.1.25-beta.0

`-- npm@7.17.0

i'm using window 10 .

i had already installed node js & npm.

## ur input matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same issue I faced previously, How did I resolved let me guide you.

I have just added **globally installed NPM to User Variable within Path**,

Please have look on below screenshot.

**Note: Once you added then restart your system,**

[image]

Comment: kumar sir thanks for ur valuable inputs it work  fantastic . and it help me lots........ #super