# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So when I run ng serve, the above error shows. I ran `npm audit fix --force`, but then also the same error is showing.

Comment: Please search this site for *not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file*. This question has been asked (and answered) here many times before. A basic search is something that you should do to try to solve the problem yourself before asking here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: No. I saw that question earlier, it was not helpful.

Comment: check node, npm & angular cli exists or not. https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is simply telling you that Angular CLI is either not installed or not added to the PATH. To solve this error, first, make sure you’re running Node 6.9 or higher. A lot of errors can be resolved by simply upgrading your Node to the latest stable version.

The command line for that is

```
node- v
```

Or

```
 node --version
```

run in cmd

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and then ( open in Windows 10) Go to Settings -> About -> at the right side -> Advance system settings.

Step - 1:

[image]

Step - 2: System Properties -> Select Advanced from the menu bar -> Click on the Environment variables

[image]

Step- 3: Click on the path and edit

[image]

Step - 4: Add missing ng path

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm


C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

[image]

Finally, restart all opened command prompts and try again.