# I am getting sopme error while installing Angular 14.2.9?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

I was trying to install Angular using: npm i @angular/cli@14.2.9 but when I check the version using ng v; the Command Prompt shows that it is not a recognized command.

Later when I install angular using: npm install -g angular-cli@latest; I am also getting various errors. Please help !!

Comment: Please show us the errors you have.

Comment: angular-cli is no longer supported. @angular/cli is the CLI you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)